# Get recordings in Twilio voice call

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php, twilio-api

I am getting output of recording json path  like  below , but when i run that path in url, output is 404 not found .
How can i get the recording in php . Is recording available for trial account.

```
["recordings"]=>
      string(112) "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACa6ee61ed761379c2bfde0cc72cd6c037/Calls/CA84b36b8677cb84b90d5b3f201d2d7110/Recordings.json"
```

Comment: you will get all the recordings [here](https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/logs/recordings)

Comment: @Punit,i want go get record on my php code using the above path

Comment: What is the code you are using that results in the 404?

Comment: I appreciate that this is well after you asked your question, but I recommend using one of Twilio's official Server-side SDKs (https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries), instead of crafting URLs yourself. That way, you don't need to worry if you got the base URL correct or not.